# How to fill the color of an app icon on android

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, xamarin, photoshop

regarding my Android app icon, how can I change the background color. For example:
[teams icon has a white background while whats app is filled green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33ZPj.png)

I want to change the background color of my app icon from white to black. Do you know how?

I tried to use different icon sizes and but it just appeared like the teams icon

Comment: use an image editor

Comment: Please RESEARCH before posting a question on StackOverflow. Google. `edit android app icon`. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is a very valid and important question. some people have allergy here for new posters.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

1. Image editor to manually edit the background of your icon.
2. or [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)